# create react app : configure Jest : Run all test files

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I would like to configure `npm test` in my server. when I run `npm test`, it invokes `react-scripts test` which triggers a prompt window ( attached screen ). How do I avoid the prompt and run all testcases in the server.

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint ."
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 37):

To run all the tests, use `"test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false"`

Comment: As documented here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#command-line-interface

Answer (score 4):

If you pass CI=true, it will run once without setting up that prompt as described at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#linux-macos-bash:

`CI=true npm test`

Answer (score 2):

When you want to run all tests you can use `npm test --watchAll`

Comment: --watchAll looking for changes in the script and it's keep spinning. Is there any other argument that avoid prompt and run all testfiles ?

Comment: ReactScripts tests all uncommited files in git. What do you want to achieve? Run all of the tests even if something not has been changed? `npm test` as well goes into watch mode

Answer (score -1):

You can just update your package.json and in the scripts section update the test one with just "test": "jest"

It should run every test file that it can find in your project

Comment: It's not that simple, because CRA programatically sets config you may be relying on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62861130/3001761