# How can I make jest run with the same config as react-script test on a create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I know I can run `npm test` which runs `react-script test` and it works, it successfully run the tests. But I'm interested in figuring out how to run `jest` directly with the same configuration `react-script` uses. Hopefully without having to replicate the configuration or ejecting the app. I started reading the source code of `react-scripts` but so far I couldn't figure it out.

The reasons for wanting this are:

- My CRA project is part of a bigger project, and I could just run `jest` on the top level and run all tests.
- In WebStorm, I can take advantage of the Jest integration, which includes:

  - Showing the list of tests that pass or fail, as they run.
  - Being able to run individual tests.
  - Doing code coverage.

If I run `jest` on my CRA app, I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Flexpoint Tech\js\exp7\frontend> jest
 FAIL  src/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    SyntaxError: C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Flexpoint Tech\js\exp7\frontend\src\App.test.tsx: Unexpected token (6:29)

      4 | 
      5 | test("renders Facebook link", () => {
    > 6 |   const {getByText} = render(<App/>)
        |                              ^
      7 |   const linkElement = getByText(/Loading.../i)
      8 |   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument()
      9 | })

      at Parser._raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:60:45)
      at Parser.raiseWithData (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:55:17)
      at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:39:17)
      at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:149:16)
      at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1174:20)
      at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:541:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:521:21)
      at Parser.parseExprOps (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:312:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:264:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:212:21)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.234s
Ran all test suites.
```

I'm trying to do this without ejecting, to not lose the benefits of CRA. I understand that if I eject I can do pretty much whatever I want.

Answer (score 11):

create-react-app Jest configuration isn't supposed to be available without ejection. `react-script test` programmatically runs Jest with dynamically generated configuration. It's exported to static configuration file on `eject`.

The problem is that ejection still doesn't allow to run tests the same way with Jest CLI because in ejected project, Jest still runs programmatically via `scripts/test.js`. The script is responsible for setting up CRA [environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), they should be additionally supplied to Jest CLI. [This](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v3.4.1/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js#L12-L24) should be evaluated in either jest.config.js or `globalSetup` file:

```
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'test';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
process.env.PUBLIC_URL = '';
require('react-scripts/config/env');
```

## Eject

Considering that unejected projects doesn't provide any benefits that are inherent to generated projects like scaffolding, it's preferable to eject as soon as any customization is needed.

## A configuration from ejected project

If it's necessary to keep the project unejected, it can be cloned and ejected, then Jest configuration (`config/jest/*.*` and `jest` entry from `package.json`) is transferred to unejected project. This can be achieved with Git branches.

## A workaround

Alternatively, its possible to retrieve generated configuration similarly to how CRA does this via a hack that relies on [`react-scripts` internals](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v3.4.1/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js#L70-L82):

*jest.config.js*

```
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'test';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
process.env.PUBLIC_URL = '';
require('react-scripts/config/env');

const path = require('path');
const createJestConfig = require('react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig');

module.exports = createJestConfig(
  relativePath => require.resolve(path.join('react-scripts', relativePath)),
  __dirname, // given that Jest config is in project root
  false
);
```