# How do I setup jest to use custom babel plugin in create-react-app project?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, create-react-app, customize-cra

I have a CRA project and i use `react-intl` package, with its `babel-plugin-formatjs` (to auto generate message IDs for translation).

I created wrapper around the `babel-plugin-formatjs` that gets some additional info about project and

In order to use the custom babel plugin in CRA, i use `customize-cra` package with a `config-overrides.js` file in the root folder like so:

```
const { override, addBabelPlugin } = require('customize-cra');

function getMyCustomBabelPlugin() {
  // extract some info and return the plugin config:
  return ['babel-plugin-formatjs', { ... // some custom config }]
}

module.exports = {
  webpack: override(
    ... // some overrides,
    addBabelPlugin(getMyCustomBabelPlugin()),
  ),
}
```

So whenever i run the `build` command babel runs the `babel-plugin-formatjs` (and adds id to strings for translation).

But whenever I want to run the CRA `test` command, jest doesn't pick up the babel config.
Some of my tests render components that use react-intl and i get errors: `[@formatjs/intl] An id must be provided to format a message.` because my custom plugin does not run.

I see that under the hood CRA runs `createJestConfig()` with the default config.
How can i make jest to use the wanted babel plugins?
Or alternatively, How do I pass jest additional plugins without ejecting or ignoring the default `createJestConfig()` of CRA?

I tried creating a `babel.config.js` file in the root folder with the custom babel plugin, but jest doesn't pick that up.
Also saw this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62861130/8252705
But wondering if it might have changed as its an old answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that may help you - https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md#usebabelrc

as addBabelPlugin does not affect config for testing, so useBabelRc picks babel config file and override default CRA's babel config

Comment: That's a shame, I hoped i wouldn't have to use a different babelrc. that means I need to now create a babelrc for `start`, `build` and `test` commands. correct?